# Integration of Unity AR in React Native (iOS)

Tags: react-native, unity-game-engine

I'm looking to incorporate Unity AR functionality into my React Native project on the iOS platform. I've tried various available packages, but I've encountered challenges when trying to integrate them. Are there any reliable packages or informative blog posts that can assist me in achieving this integration successfully?

Answer (score 2):

As you have said that you have tried various available packages, here are some approaches and packages you can consider .

1. Search for "**React Native Unity View**" on the NPM package registry /
   GitHub or [click here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-unity-view)
2. Search for **ARKit for Unity** on google .

***OR***

you can check out these articles on how make AR apps in react native.

3. [How to implement AR based App using React Native?](https://medium.com/simform-engineering/what-is-augmented-reality-how-to-implement-ar-using-react-native-2340bdba9a8d)
4. [Crafting AR apps with React Native](https://medium.com/ascentic-technology/crafting-ar-apps-with-react-native-a9040cf40042)

let me know if this helps .

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it, just override `RTCVideoCapturer` and modify the `pixelBuffer`, see example here:

https://github.com/gorastudio-ceo/SCNRecorder/issues/33